# Laravel - New Model Instance return 500 internal server error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm a newbie to Laravel. I have been using a user model for authentication and user module. I have created a new module named as Management. I had like to use a new Management model for the new module. I have created a Management model but when I create an instance in controller then it return internal server error.

Code:
    $management = new Management;

Table Name: Management
Model:

```
class Management extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'Management';
}
```

I created it manually.

Please advice.

Comment: Set `debug` to `true` in `app/config/app.php` and you'll see what error you get.

Comment: @Marwelln: Thanks for your response. Yes, but I couldn't see errors

Comment: @Marwelln: I found the issue, I have to remove implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface otherwise create the auth related methods.

Comment: Why users must to implements this interfaces? My Users don't need authorization. Users in my domain don't make login, not have username, password, etc. Are just data from an external system updated via a restfull api.